Linq ThenInclude and bridge table
ER diagram (do excuse my lack of flowchart skills):

Models:
public class MainObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubObject> SubObjects{ get; set; } = [];
}

public class SubObject
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int MainObjectId {get; set;}
    public int TableAObjectId {get; set;}
    public int TableBObjectId {get; set;}

    public TableAObject TableAObject {get; set;}
    public TableBObject TableBObject {get; set;}

}

public class TableAObject
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public ICollection<BridgeTableObject> BridgeTableObjects { get; set; } = [];

}

public class TableBObject
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public ICollection<BridgeTableObject> BridgeTableObjects { get; set; } = [];

}

public class BridgeTableObject
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int TableAObjectId {get; set;}
    public int TableBObjectId {get; set;}   

    public BridgeTableDetailObject BridgeTableDetailObject {get; set;}

}

public class BridgeTableDetailObject
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

DTOs
Pretty much mirrors the models. Please note that I am not much concerned about where the BridgeTable objects show up; they don't need to appear under both TableA and TableB objects. But since the BridgeTable (as the name suggests and as I mentioned in one of the comments below, is  a link to TableA and Table B, the retrieved objects should reflect that). I am just not sure how to construct the query to get that.
public class MainDto
{
    public List<SubObjectDto> SubObjects{ get; set; } = [];
}

public class SubObjectDto
{
    public TableAObjectDto TableAObjectDto { get; set; }
    public TableBObjectDto TableBObjectDto { get; set; }

}


public class TableAObjectDto 
{
    public List<BridgeTableObjectDto> BridgeTableObjectDto{ get; set; } = [];
}


public class TableBObjectDto
{
}


public class BridgeTableObjectDto
{
    public BridgeTableDetailObjectDto BridgeTableDetailObjectDto{ get; set; }
}

Here is my query:
mainObjects.Where(m => m.Id == 1)
  .Include(m => m.subObjects)
  .ThenInclude(s => s.tableAObject)
  .ThenInclude(ta => ta.bridgeTableObjects)
  .ThenInclude(bt => bt.bridgeTableDetailObject)
  .Include(m => m.subObjects).ThenInclude(s => s.tableBObject)

Problem I am trying to solve:
As you can see, the query gives me a list of subObjects and each will have a tableAObject  with a list of bridgeTableObjects.
Basically, the query translates to a join between TableA and BridgeTable only, bringing back multiple BridgeTable objects. What I need is also a join of BridgeTable with table B so I get a single BridgeTable object. Or in other words: For a Main object with id = 1, get a list of Sub objects such that each Sub object should (either via TableA or TableB object) get a single record of BridgeTable object. Is this possible with Include/ThenInclude in a single query?
So, the list I get should be something like given below but I should have only one bridgeTableObject (and not a list). This is the tricky part for me since I can't figure out how I will get the BridgeTable to join with both TableA and TableB in the query (or not sure if that's even possible).
mainObject
  subObject[0]
      tableAObject
         **bridgeTableObject**
             bridgeTableDetailObject
      tableBObject
  subObject[1]
     .
     .
     .

  
   


I do not understand problem, show your filters. Includes needed only for loading entities NOT filtering. And for better understanding, post your model classes, we cannot create LINQ query from image.

Apologies for the confusion. I did list down the entities and the navigational properties that I am using in the query. Kind of abstract but thought it gave an idea of what I am trying to do while keeping things concise.  Sorry, if the word "filter" was misleading. What I meant was that my current query will translate to a join between TableA and BridgeTable, and will bring back multiple bridgetable records. What I want is also a join with TableB so I get a single bridgetable record. So the question is: can I achieve that with Include/ThenInclude in a single query.

bridgeTableObjects.Where(...).Include(b => b.A.Include(b => b.B)? You better show the class model if this is off the mark.

I have included the models. Thanks.

To get the structure you want you'll have to project into DTO classes since each TableObject has a collection of BridgeTableObjects, that's never going to be one BridgeTableObject.

Try to be clear in the title of your question. Is it a Join problem? poor designed entities? A mapping problem? ...

@AZeus, so you need only first collection items? Do you have DTO class which is needed for result?

Gert Arnold I do have DTO classes and the last list that is how I am getting the values. I get a mainObject that has a list of subObjects. Each subObject has a tableAObject that in turn has a list of bridgeTableObjects (and that is the problem). So are you trying to say I need to get the list filtered during projection/mapping to DTO?

Gert Arnold  - BTW, I don't need to have BridgetTableObjects under both TableObject. I do however need to retrieve the values that is a join to both the TableObjects. Or in other words: Get the mainObject with id =1 that has a list of subObjects. Each subObject has a tableAObject and tableBObject. (Tricky Part) And a BridgetTableObject that is a result of join to both TableObject.

Juanma Feiliu : This is database first so I don't have much control over the entities relationship or db design. The BridgeTable ,as the name suggests, ties TableA to TableB and should be retrieved as such. However, I am unable to construct a query to do so.  As mentioned above, I don't care where the BridgeTableObject appears in the DTO.
